# How do I make MIDI playback work on a Inspiron 531s?

Tags: 11.04, dell, soundcard, midi

I have a windows vista inspiron 531s with ubuntu 11.04 & a realtek ALC888 soundcard everything with ubuntu works fine except for midi playback in my softwares like noteworthy composer & such.

Could there be a way to fix this? perhaps an audigy soundcard might be compatible with ubuntu 11.04 architecture. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Normally you won't be able to play back midi by default. Install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` (should pull in everything), and then try again.

You may also need to search for sound fonts in synaptic and install a package (you will need fluidsynth - but I think this gets pulled in by the package I mentioned earlier).